# Why manipulate filtered column will affect index efficiency?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm reading "Tsql Fundamental" by Ben Itzik.

The author briefly mentioned that we shouldn't manipulate the filtered column if we want to use index efficiently. But he didn't really go into detail as to why this is the case.

So could someone please kindly explain the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The author briefly mentioned that we shouldn't manipulate the filtered column if we want to use index efficiently

What author mentions is called [SARGABILITY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Assume this statement

```
select * from t1 where name='abc'
```

Assume,you have an index on above filtered column

,then the query is Sargable

But not below one

```
select * from t1 where len(name)=3
```

When SQL is presented with above query,the only way ,it can filter out the data is to scan the table and then apply predicate to each row

Answer (score 2):

Think of an index as being like a telephone directory (hopefully that's still a familiar enough concept) where everyone is listed by their surnames followed by their addresses.

This index is useful if you want to locate someone's phone number and you know their surname (and maybe their address).

But what if you want to locate everyone who (to steal [TheGameiswar's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852331/15498)) has a 3 letter surname - is the index useful to you? It may be slightly more useful than having to go and visit every house in town<sup>1</sup>, but it's not nearly so efficient as being able to just jump to the appropriate surnames. You have to search the entire book.

Similarly, if you want to locate everyone who lives on a particular street, the index isn't so useful<sup>2</sup> - you have to search through the entire book to make sure you've found everyone. Or to locate everyone whose surname *ends* with `Son`, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is the analogy for when a database may choose to perform an index scan to satisfy a query simply because the index is smaller and so is easier than a full table scan.

<sup>2</sup>This is the analogy for a query that isn't attempting to filter on the left-most column in the index.

Answer (score 1):

WHERE clause in a SQL query use predicates to filter the rows. Predicate is an expression, that determines whether an argument applied on a database object is  true or false. Example : "Salary > 5000".

Relational models use predicates as a core element in filtering the data. These predicates should be written in certain form known as "**Search Arguments**" in order for the query optimizer to use the indexes effectively on the attributes used in the WHERE clause to filter data.
A predicate in the form - "*column - operator - value*" or "*value - operator - column*" is considered an appropriate search argument. Example - Salary = 1000 or Salary > 5000. As you can see, the column name should appear **ALONE** on one side of the expression and the constant or calculated value should be on the other side to form a valid search argument. The moment a built-in function like MAX , MIN, DATEADD or DATEDIFF etc was used on the column name, the expression is no longer treated as a search argument and the query optimizer won't use the indexes on those column names.

I hope this is clear.